# Can I auto switch user's keyboard input method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, input

I would like to auto switch user's input method when some form field is being focused.
For example,
Here are 2 fields:
Field 1 (chinese name):***_*___**
Field 2 (japanese name):**__*_***

The page can auto switch input method to chinese in field 1,
and can auto switch input method to japanese in field 2 when we focus on the field

Would there be some jquery script to do this?
Or there would be an alternative in other script language?

Comment: How does the *input method* alter the characters?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way doing so from within the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this (and probably no fully reliable way as i would imagine keyboard layouts differ). However you could try looking for some keycode mappings you can implement (or if you really want this, create your own mappings).

If you created/found some keycode mappings, you could use the event keycode to translate the key pressed to what that key would do if the keyboard "language" had been changed in the OS.

You could create your own mappings by setting up some javascript to capture the keycode and character, and store them in an object. Once you've hit all relevant keys you will have a map of keycodes to characters which you can output, save and then re-use to alter the input on every "keyup".

Who knows, if i get bored i might have a look at doing this for a bit of fun and see if it actually works.

**EDIT**

I've actually got quite interested in this now. I wrote a bit of javascript and it does indeed work (switch keyboard language in OS and i could get arabic characters which produced the same keycode as the english ones, meaning it was seeing the same keycode for the same keypressed irrelevant of language)

So i got thinking, could we use a premade map for an OS? Linux is open source after all, so lets find some mappings. I googled (i need to google more) but i found this for a random language. http://rffr.de/de-dvorak-keysym.xmodmap . Which means that if you look hard enough you will get the mappings you need (im sure theres a linux repo for all the languages somewhere, i'll find it eventually)

Then its just a case of creating a parser to turn it into a nice javascript object and a simply jquery plugin.

I can feel a GIT coming on

Comment: Edited with a little research, however i'll probably end up doing it for you at this rate. It is mildly more interesting that the code im being paid to type after all.